# In jena: How can i load an ontology once?

Tags: sparql, jena, ontology

I need to load an ontology once only in Jena. My method which contains the SPARQL query also contains the

```java
Model model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );
model =  FileManager.get().loadModel("c:/jena/ICD.owl");
```

It all works well except every time a conduct a query the method reloads the ontology. 
I need the ontology to be loaded once only and the 'model' variable to be 'seen' in the method. If I move the two model statements into the main class the method can't see 'model'. There are no global variables in Java.

Here is the code:

```
 class store {          
        Model model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(     OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );
         public void myQuery() {
                String pattern = "\\#(.*)$";
                model =  FileManager.get().loadModel("c:/jena/ICD.owl");
                String singleQueryWord1="VEnTRICULAR FIBRILLATION";
                String firstQueryWord2="pedestrian";
                String secondQueryWord2="car";
                String queryPattern1="("+singleQueryWord1+"(.*))";
                String queryPattern2="("+firstQueryWord2+"(.|\\n)*"+secondQueryWord2+")|("+secondQueryWord2+"(.|\\n)*"+firstQueryWord2+")";

                Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);


                String queryString = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\r\n" + 
                        "PREFIX afn:<http://jena.apache.org/ARQ/function#>\r\n"+
                        "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>\r\n" + 
                        "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>\r\n" + 
                        "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\r\n" + 
                        "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>\r\n" + 
                        "SELECT DISTINCT ?subject ?object\r\n" + 

                        "   WHERE {\r\n"+

                         "?subject dc:title ?object \r\n" +

                        "FILTER regex(?object,\""+ queryPattern1 +"\",\"i\")\r\n" + 
                        //"FILTER regex( ?object,\"( pedestrian (.|\\n)* car )|( car (.|\\n)* pedestrian )\",\"i\")\r\n"+
                        "}"
                         ;

                  Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString) ;
                  try (QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model)) {
                        ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect() ;
                        if(!results.hasNext()) {
                            System.out.println("No results");
                        }else
                        for ( ; results.hasNext() ; )
                        {

                            QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution();
                            Resource subj = (Resource) soln.get("?subject");

                            String subStr = subj.toString();
                            Matcher m = r.matcher(subStr);

                                if(m.find()) {
                            Literal obj = (Literal) soln.get("?object");
                            System.out.println(m.group()+" ........ "+obj);
                            }

                            m.reset();

                        }  


                  } catch(Exception e) { 
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                         }
                }                                       
    }
```

Many thanks for any suggestions.
Phil

Comment: And loading the ontology in the constructor does not work why? Please show the method that executes the query!

Comment: "There are no global variables in Java" -> what?

Comment: Thanks fo ryour reply ASKW. According to David Flannigan, in 'java in a nutshell', there are no global variables. Instread, variables are declared in a class and forms part of that class. I was trying to put the constructor in the Main class.  However, I think I may have solved it by declaring a new class called 'store' and placing the method 'my query' inside it. It is just a bit of learning fun. Here is the code:

Comment: I have placed the code into the original question above.

Comment: And how did you call the method before? I mean, in Java you have classes and objects, both of which can have variables.

Comment: What you did is not enough! You have to load the file in the construct as well. Therefore, use an explicit constructor for the class `store` please.

Comment: I just ran all the code in 'myQuery' in the main. It worked well and as I said earlier. Unfortunatly the class just reloaded the ontology every time I ran a query which is a wast of energy. So I'm thinking I'll turn it into a helper.java and maybe use public dataset model.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what you're doing. Java provides constructors for classes. And then you can instantiate such a Java class, which will call the constructor in which you load the file into the Jena model.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I can load the ontology in the main method once only. Then I pass the model into the myQuery method. I sould be able to access the myQuery with getter and setters and not have to load the ontology every time I do a query.

```
public class SPARQLVeriations {
static private String singleQueryWord1="ventricular fibrillation";
static private String firstQueryWord2;
static private String secondQueryWord2;
static private Model model;
SPARQLVeriations sv = new SPARQLVeriations();

public static void main(String[] args) {

     model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );
    model = FileManager.get().loadModel("c:/jena/ICD.owl");


     myQuery(model,singleQueryWord1,firstQueryWord2,secondQueryWord2);   


}

private static void myQuery(Model model,String singleQueryWord1,String firstQueryWord2,String secondQueryWord2) {
    String pattern = "\\#(.*)$";

   // String singleQueryWord1="VEnTRICULAR FIBRILLATION";
    //String firstQueryWord2="pedestrian";
    //String secondQueryWord2="car";
    String queryPattern1="("+singleQueryWord1+"(.*))";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);


    String queryString = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\r\n" + 
            "PREFIX afn:<http://jena.apache.org/ARQ/function#>\r\n"+
            "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>\r\n" + 
            "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>\r\n" + 
            "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\r\n" + 
            "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>\r\n" + 
            "SELECT DISTINCT ?subject ?object\r\n" + 

            "   WHERE {\r\n"+

             "?subject dc:title ?object \r\n" +

            "FILTER regex(?object,\""+ queryPattern1 +"\",\"i\")\r\n" + 
            //"FILTER regex( ?object,\"( pedestrian (.|\\n)* car )|( car (.|\\n)* pedestrian )\",\"i\")\r\n"+
            "}"
             ;

      Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString) ;
      try (QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model)) {
            ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect() ;
            if(!results.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println("No results");
            }else
            for ( ; results.hasNext() ; )
            {

                QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution();
                Resource subj = (Resource) soln.get("?subject");

                String subStr = subj.toString();
                Matcher m = r.matcher(subStr);

                    if(m.find()) {
                Literal obj = (Literal) soln.get("?object");
                System.out.println(m.group()+" ........ "+obj);
                }

                m.reset();

            }  


      } catch(Exception e) { 
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
             }

}
public void setQuery1() { }
```

}

Comment: I don't understand why you don't make use of object-oriented programming in Java...for example ,what's the meaning of `SPARQLVeriations sv = new SPARQLVeriations();` here? having an instance of itself as object variable?!